# PySide6 comes with segmentation fault on Mac

Tags: python, qml, pyside6

I am using Python 3.8.6 and PySide 6.0.1 and get a segmentation fault running the below sample.
When I comment the Text {} element the sample runs.

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine("view.qml")
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow 
{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: "QML Demo"

    Text 
    {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        text: "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Comment: Also tried Python 3.9.2...same error

Comment: What operating system? How did you install or build PySide6? Can you attach a debugger and get a stack trace?

Comment: Working on Catalina 10.15.7 and used pip3 to install PySide

Comment: Same problem with PyQt6...

Comment: With PyQt5 it is working fine.

Comment: same -- runs without children, segfaults with Text or Rectangle as child

- Python 3.9.4

- PySide6  6.1.1  (via pip)

- fresh virtual environment

- all version numbers removed from QML imports

- OSX big sur 11.4

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'm facing the exact same issue since upgrading from PySide2 to PySide6, has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code on Mac but as a suggestion you can remove all version numbers from imports in QML.
This is the only difference I can see here between PyQt5 and PyQt6.
(however your code works on Ubuntu 20.04)